# Apache jMeter - Get field name from JSON extractor

Tags: json, testing, jmeter, extract

I'm using Apache jMeter 5.3. I have a HTTP request which returns JSON response like this:

```
{
 "result": {
   "certificates": {
     "4b89aa6c131": "MIID2zCC...",
     "ab19aa6c144": "MIID0zCC..."}
  }
}
```

Is there any way to extract first field name from "certificates" object ("4b89aa6c131" in this example) using JSON Extractor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055190/how-to-extract-values-from-json-in-jmeter-when-the-keys-are-unkown) using JSR223 PostProcessor instead JSON Extractor: